# How to send data from the Kinect to an Arduino using OpenNI libraries in C++ using Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, serial-port, arduino, kinect

I am working on a project that takes the right and left hand values from a user and then sends data to the Arduino.  My current problem is that the Arduino is not receiving anything from what I can tell. Right now we have it set a pin to 5V; if it receives a "2" or a "3" and it is set to 0V. When we run the program on the Arduino and the Kinect we don't ever see the output of the pin ever drop to 0V.

The full code I have is:

```
#pragma region Includes
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Includes
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#include <XnOS.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <XnCppWrapper.h>

using namespace xn;

#pragma endregion

#pragma region Defines
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Defines
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#define SAMPLE_XML_PATH "../Data/SamplesConfig.xml"

// Pose to Use Added
#define POSE_TO_USE "Psi"
#pragma endregion

#pragma region Global Nodes
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Globals
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Nodes Added for Skeletal Tracking
UserGenerator g_UserGenerator;
#pragma endregion

#pragma region Functions
// Functions Added for Skeletal Tracking

void XN_CALLBACK_TYPE User_NewUser(xn::UserGenerator& generator, XnUserID nId, void* pCookie)
{
    printf("New User: %d\n", nId);
    g_UserGenerator.GetPoseDetectionCap().StartPoseDetection(POSE_TO_USE, nId);
}

void XN_CALLBACK_TYPE User_LostUser(xn::UserGenerator& generator, XnUserID nId, void* pCookie)
{}

void XN_CALLBACK_TYPE Pose_Detected(xn::PoseDetectionCapability& pose, const XnChar* strPose, XnUserID nId, void* pCookie)
{
    printf("Pose %s for user %d\n", strPose, nId);
    g_UserGenerator.GetPoseDetectionCap().StopPoseDetection(nId);
    g_UserGenerator.GetSkeletonCap().RequestCalibration(nId, TRUE);
}

void XN_CALLBACK_TYPE Calibration_Start(xn::SkeletonCapability& capability, XnUserID nId, void* pCookie)
{
    printf("Starting calibration for user %d\n", nId);
}

void XN_CALLBACK_TYPE Calibration_End(xn::SkeletonCapability& capability, XnUserID nId, XnBool bSuccess, void* pCookie)
{
    if (bSuccess)
    {
        printf("User calibrated\n");
        g_UserGenerator.GetSkeletonCap().StartTracking(nId);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Failed to calibrate user %d\n", nId);
        g_UserGenerator.GetPoseDetectionCap().StartPoseDetection(POSE_TO_USE, nId);
    }
}
#pragma endregion

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    //System::IO::Ports::SerialPort^  serialPort1;
    //serialPort1 = (gcnew System::IO::Ports::SerialPort(this->components));
    //serialPort1->PortName="COM3";

    XnStatus nRetVal = XN_STATUS_OK;

    Context context;
    nRetVal = context.Init();
    // TODO: check error code

    // Create the user generator
    nRetVal = g_UserGenerator.Create(context);
    // TODO: check error code

    XnCallbackHandle h1, h2, h3;
    g_UserGenerator.RegisterUserCallbacks(User_NewUser, User_LostUser, NULL, h1);
    g_UserGenerator.GetPoseDetectionCap().RegisterToPoseCallbacks(Pose_Detected, NULL, NULL, h2);
    g_UserGenerator.GetSkeletonCap().RegisterCalibrationCallbacks(Calibration_Start, Calibration_End, NULL, h3);

    // Set the profile
    g_UserGenerator.GetSkeletonCap().SetSkeletonProfile(XN_SKEL_PROFILE_ALL);
    // Start generating
    nRetVal = context.StartGeneratingAll();
    // TODO: check error code
    printf("Start Pose:\n");

    while (TRUE)
    {
        // Update to next frame
        nRetVal = context.WaitAndUpdateAll();
        // TODO: check error code
        // Extract hand position of each tracked user
        XnUserID aUsers[1];
        XnUInt16 nUsers = 1;
        g_UserGenerator.GetUsers(aUsers, nUsers);
        for (int i = 0; i < nUsers; ++i)
        {
            if (g_UserGenerator.GetSkeletonCap().IsTracking(aUsers[i]))
            {
                //serialPort1->Open();

                //Get head position
                /*XnSkeletonJointPosition Head;
                g_UserGenerator.GetSkeletonCap().GetSkeletonJointPosition(aUsers[i], XN_SKEL_HEAD, Head);
                printf("%d: (%f,%f,%f) [%f]\n", aUsers[i], Head.position.X, Head.position.Y, Head.position.Z, Head.fConfidence);*/

                //Get right hand position
                XnSkeletonJointPosition RightHand;
                g_UserGenerator.GetSkeletonCap().GetSkeletonJointPosition(aUsers[i], XN_SKEL_LEFT_HAND, RightHand);
                printf("%d: (%f,%f,%f) [%f]\n", aUsers[i], RightHand.position.X, RightHand.position.Y, RightHand.position.Z, RightHand.fConfidence);



                //http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13547574/visual-studio-2010-arduino-serial-communication
                int portspeed;
                int centerpix;
                int xmid;
                HANDLE hDevice = CreateFile("COM7",GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE,NULL,OPEN_EXISTING,0,0);
                DCB lpTest;
                GetCommState(hDevice,&lpTest);
                lpTest.BaudRate = CBR_9600;
                lpTest.ByteSize = 8;
                lpTest.Parity = NOPARITY;
                lpTest.StopBits = ONESTOPBIT;
                SetCommState(hDevice,&lpTest);
                DWORD btsIO;

                if (RightHand.position.X<0)
                {
                    char test[] = "2";
                    WriteFile(hDevice,test,strlen(test),&btsIO,NULL);
                    printf("Right ");
                }
                else
                {
                    char test[] = "3";
                    WriteFile(hDevice,test,strlen(test),&btsIO,NULL);
                    printf("Left");
                }
                FlushFileBuffers(hDevice);
            }
            else
            {
                printf("Not tracking.\n");
            }
        }
    }

    // Clean up
    context.Shutdown();

    return 0;
}`
```

The code for the Arduino is:

```
int incomingByte = 0;   // For incoming serial data
void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(9600);     // Opens serial port, sets data rate to 9600 bit/s
}

void loop()
{
    // Send data only when you receive data:
    //if (Serial.available() > 0)
    //{
        incomingByte = Serial.read();
        if (incomingByte==50)   //if =2
            analogWrite(9,0);
        //else
         //   analogWrite(9,0);

        if (incomingByte==51)   //if =3
            analogWrite(9,255);
        //else 
        //    analogWrite(9,0);

        delay(3000);
    //}
    //else
    //    analogWrite(9,255);
}
```

This code is currently in a while loop for every time the Kinect receives a new value for the user's right hand.

Is there something I can fix in my code or use different code?

Comment: You don't explain the problem you are having with the code.  What is the issue you are trying to resolve?  Are you sending this in the `SkeletonFrameReady` callback?

Comment: My current problem is that the Arduino is not receiving anything from what I can tell. Right now we have it set a pin to 5V; if it receives a "2" or a "3" and it is set to 0V. When we run the program on the Arduino and the Kinect we don't ever see the output of the pin ever drop to 0V.